# Android kotlin MapView bug with Bottom sheet dialog

Tags: android, kotlin, google-maps, android-mapview

When I use a Google MapView element with a bottom sheet dialog and scroll the view is shown under the Dialog, is it a bug? and is there a solution to fix it?

[image: MapView bug]

Comment: How are you implementing the layout? Like changing the z-order of the scrollview.